# Request to rename [ember-2.0.0] to [ember.js-2.x]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Over the last days, I saw the [ember-2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember-2.0.0) tag slowly being used alongside new Ember.js SO questions, so before this tag becomes widespread, I would like to propose a name change to [ember.js-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js-2.x) for the following reasons:

**1.** It will maintain a similar structure to [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js) tag.

**2.** [ember-2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember-2.0.0) has a certain connotation of a specific version of Ember.js.

**3.** Sonner or later, Ember.js will get to 3.x, so [ember.js-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js-2.x) will set a precedent for when the times comes.

**4.** Making the assumption that changing [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js) is not viable, [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js) would remain the tag for [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js) while a separated [ember.js-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js-1.x) tag would be created for all new questions that still uses 1.x.

With that, new questions would have [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js) followed by which version the OP is using...

Answer (score 1):

In the intervening 4 years, version 3 of the Ember.js library was released, so there was a bit more clean-up to do here to truly bring about consistency. Here's what we have now:

## [ember.js-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js-3) ← [ember-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember-3)

## [ember.js-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js-2) ← [ember-2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember-2.0.0)

I see no point in having a ".x" in the tag name. Just mentioning the major version is sufficient, while reducing clutter.

I'm not sure that version-specific tags are actually *useful* here. We prefer not to use them unless there is something quite special about that version that would make it an important way to group questions. (Note that the [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js) tag wiki excerpt contains an admonition to always specify the version of Ember that you are using when describing your issue in the question. I wonder how many people do that?) And, when version-specific tags are used, we *always* want to combine them with the "main" tag, [ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js). If I had some subject-matter expertise, I could actually evaluate the questions with the version-specific tags and see if there was any merit to the version-specific tags. If not, I could merge them both into the "main" tag. But I don't know anything about JavaScript, much less this library, so I have to punt on that, leaving the version-specific tags in place for now. At least the naming convention is standardized.